# Android - Passing a custom string as per user input

Tags: java, string

I am creating an android app in which I take user inputs from edittext fields and then I pass those inputs as Strings into a Custom String.

I am having trouble while eliminating the empty Strings which are provided by the user.

Below is my code:

```
EditText siteName = findViewById(R.id.editSite); //these types are of EditText values provided by the user
            strSite = "site%3A" + siteName.getText().toString();
            if (strSite.matches("")) {
                strSite = null;
                return;
            }

            fileType = findViewById(R.id.editFile);
            strFile = "filetype%3A" + fileType.getText().toString();
            if (strFile.matches("")) {
                strFile = null;
                return;
            }

            inUrl = findViewById(R.id.editUrl);
            strUrl = "inurl%3A" + inUrl.getText().toString();
            if (strUrl.matches("")) {
                strUrl = null;
                return;
            }

            inTitle = findViewById(R.id.editTitle);
            strTitle = "intext%3A" + inTitle.getText().toString();
            if (strTitle.matches("")) {
                strTitle = null;
                return;
            }

            indexOf = findViewById(R.id.editIndex);
            strIndex = "indexof%3A" + indexOf.getText().toString();
            if (strIndex.matches("")) {
                strIndex = null;
                return;
            }

            String dork = strSite +" "+ strFile+" "+strUrl+" "+strTitle+" "+strIndex; //this is the custom string
```

So the motive here is to set empty Strings empty in `String dork`

Please let me know if it can be done this way or using a checkbox would be easy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please explain clearly what you need to do.

Comment: Hey @AIK I have added the motive within the question, please let me know if there any specific thing you need regarding the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after doing some research I have found the solution for above problem.
It was quite simple just use String type ArrayList then push the non-empty strings into it, please find below is the code:

```
ArrayList<String> arrstr;
   arrstr = new ArrayList<String>();
   if(!(strSite.equals("site%3A"))){
      arrstr.add(strSite);
   }else {
      arrstr.add("");
   } 
// same for other string inputs from user.
  ...
```

Converting String Array into string:
Used [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) so that I can use `StringUtils.join`

```
String dork = StringUtils.join(arrstr, " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly(if user provide empty string then you want to set dork as empty) you need something like this (put a check if the user provided not empty string)

```
String dork = "";

if (!(siteName.getText().toString().equals("")) {

 //do rest of it
    dork = strSite +" "+ strFile+" "+strUrl+" "+strTitle+" "+strIndex;

}
```

**NOTE:** Do check for the `null` also

Comment: Hey @Debmalya, I have a quick question here, do there is a need of using cascaded if statements where you've mentioned `//do rest of it` or just consecutive if statements only?

Comment: Both can be done. You need to implemet your logic to get your custom string. It's basically depend on your logic and personal preference

Comment: I believe I have tried this before this wasn't working for me, anyways thanks for helping.
I am looking for something like, if we can push our string into `String dork` without mentioning other User Strings, not like we have done above: `dork = strSite +" "+ strFile+" "+strUrl+" "+strTitle+" "+strIndex;`

Comment: please see my solution, I have found a work around to it :)